# how to get value of checkbox in table in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I need to get the value of a checkbox provided with span in table rows. The code below is part of my project. The HTML code is for dynamic my table and javascript code is for getting the value of elements which does not work for the checkbox (it works for other input elements).

my table:

```
var html = '<tr class="rows" id="r'+row_id+'" style="">';
html += '<td><input type="text" id = "abc" style="height:30px" class="rtl form-control" size="20" name="" /></td>';
html += '<td><input type="text" style="height:30px" class="rtl form-control" size="25" name="" /></td>';
html += '<td style="text-align: center;">'+
'<label class="switch switch-label switch-pill switch-primary switch-sm" style="direction:ltr;">'+
'<input type="checkbox" value="1" data-size="mini" class="switch-input">'+
'<span class="switch-slider" data-checked="✓" data-unchecked="✕" unchecked></span></label>'+
'</td>'+
'<td><button class="btn btn-warning DT_action_minus" id="btn'+row_id+'" style="height:25px;width:25px;padding:0px;" href="#" title="delete">'+
'<i class="fa fa-minus" style="align:center" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></td>'+
'</tr>';
```

getting the values:

```
var tbl = document.getElementById('descriptive-table');
var rCount = tbl.rows.length;
var cCount = 3;
var allArray = [];
for (var i = 1; i <rCount; i++){
    var rowArray = [];
    for (var j = 0; j <cCount; j++){                            
        rowArray.push(tbl.rows[i].cells[j].children[0].value);
    }
    allArray.push(rowArray);
}
console.log(allArray);
```

Comment: `children[0]` is `label` in some rows.

Comment: yes, but there is an input inside it. I need its value if it is checked or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it like this and it works for me:

```
$('.en-ajax-button').on('click', function(e){
     var tbl = document.getElementById('descriptive-table');
     var rCount = tbl.rows.length;
     var cCount = 3;
     var allArray = [];
     for (var i = 1; i <rCount; i++){
          var rowArray = [];
          for (var j = 0; j <cCount; j++){
              if (j != 2){
                   rowArray.push(tbl.rows[i].cells[j].children[0].value);
              } 
              else{
                   rowArray.push(tbl.rows[i].cells[j].children[0].children[0].checked);
              }
          }
          allArray.push(rowArray);
    }
    console.log(allArray);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the value of a checkbox you need to evaluate the "checked" attribute not the value:

```
tbl.rows[i].cells[j].children[0].checked <--- true or false
```

Also just a tip, when you're using a really big block of html in javascript, use template literals ( these ---> ``). They let you write multi line strings which is just a lot more readable, e.g.:

```
const myHMTLBlock = `
  <div>
     <span></span>
  <div/>
`
```

Comment: I changed my code like this and it returns undefined!!
`
for (var i = 1; i <rCount; i++){
    var rowArray = [];
    for (var j = 0; j <cCount; j++){
        if (j != 2){
            rowArray.push(tbl.rows[i].cells[j].children[0].value);
        } 
        else{
           rowArray.push(tbl.rows[i].cells[j].children[0].checked);
        }
    }
    allArray.push(rowArray);
}
`

Answer (score 0):

you can't access the value of checkbox by **.value**.
it accessible with **.checked** .
so you should check the **type** of children. if it's not equal to check box push value but if it's equal to "checkbox" you should push checked.
feel free if you need more description.

Answer (score 0):

```
Angular Version 13
```

Here Is my working Code..

```
 Declare First...
 lang_array: any[] = [];
 lang_values:any={};

If CheckBox Is Selected Then Output Will Be true OtherWise false.

**My Table In HTML File**

    <div class="table-responsive">
                  <table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-striped" (change)="CheckBox($event)">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Language</th>
                        <th scope="col">Speak</th>
                        <th scope="col">Write</th>
                        <th scope="col">Read</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      <tr >
                        <th>Marathi</th>
                        <td><input value="marathi_speak" type="checkbox"></td>
                        <td><input value="marathi_write" type="checkbox"></td>
                        <td><input value="marathi_read" type="checkbox"></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th>Hindi</th>
                        <td><input value="hindi_speak" type="checkbox"></td>
                        <td><input value="hindi_write" type="checkbox"></td>
                        <td><input value="hindi_read" type="checkbox"></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th>English</th>
                        <td><input value="english_speak" type="checkbox"></td>
                        <td><input value="english_write" type="checkbox"></td>
                        <td><input value="english_read" type="checkbox"></td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </div>


My Code In .ts File

  CheckBox(e: any) {
console.log(e.target.attributes[1].value);
if(e.target.attributes[1].value)
{ 
  if( this.lang_array.includes(e.target.attributes[1].value))
  {
    console.log("value exist");
    const index=this.lang_array.indexOf(e.target.attributes[1].value);
    console.log(index);
    if(index>-1)
    {
      this.lang_array.splice(index,1)
      this.lang_values=this.lang_array;
      console.log("Language values",this.lang_values);  
      const marathi_values=
      {
        marathi_speaks:this.lang_values.includes("marathi_speak"),
        marathi_write:this.lang_values.includes("marathi_write"),
        marathi_read:this.lang_values.includes("marathi_read"),
      }
      console.log("marathi_values",marathi_values);  
      const hindi_values=
      {
        hindi_speaks:this.lang_values.includes("hindi_speak"),
        hindi_write:this.lang_values.includes("hindi_write"),
        hindi_read:this.lang_values.includes("hindi_read"),
      }
      console.log("Hindi_values",hindi_values);
      const english_speak=
      {
        english_speak:this.lang_values.includes("english_speak"),
        english_write:this.lang_values.includes("english_write"),
        english_read:this.lang_values.includes("english_read"),
      }
      console.log("English_values",english_speak);
    }
  }
  else {
    this.lang_array.push(e.target.attributes[1].value);
    this.lang_values=this.lang_array;
    console.log(this.lang_values);
    const marathi_values=
    {
      marathi_speaks:this.lang_values.includes("marathi_speak"),
      marathi_write:this.lang_values.includes("marathi_write"),
      marathi_read:this.lang_values.includes("marathi_read"),
    }
    console.log("marathi_values",marathi_values);
    const hindi_values=
    {
      hindi_speaks:this.lang_values.includes("hindi_speak"),
      hindi_write:this.lang_values.includes("hindi_write"),
      hindi_read:this.lang_values.includes("hindi_read"),
    }
    console.log("Hindi_values",hindi_values);
    const english_speak=
    {
      english_speaks:this.lang_values.includes("english_speak"),
      english_write:this.lang_values.includes("english_write"),
      english_read:this.lang_values.includes("english_read"),
    }
    console.log("English_values",english_speak);
  }
}
else{
  console.log("next Block");
}
```

}