# Getting a checkbox from a table field

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

Good afternoon, below is the code in it I am getting fields from my table. The 0 field contains a checkbox, how can I find out if it is checked or not(true or false)? You need to change this line: console.log (td.item (f));

```html
var table = document.getElementsByClassName("table-sm");
for (var i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
  var tr = table.item(i).getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (var j = 0; j < tr.length; j++) {
    var trr = tr.item(j);
    var td = tr.item(j).getElementsByTagName("td");

    for (var f = 0; f < td.length; f++) {
      if (f === 0) console.log(td.item(f));
      console.log(td.item(f).innerText);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the HTML aswell. And have a read here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to get value of checkbox in table in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56303317/how-to-get-value-of-checkbox-in-table-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, please learn about [JavaScript Table API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement) is much better than just making complex for-loops.

> Next time please add full code (HTML/JavaScript) so people can help you.

Now let's fix your code.

#### Suppose we have this table

```html
<table class="table-sm" id="myTable">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Checkbox</th>
         <th>ID</th>
         <th>Name</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td><input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" checked /></td>
         <td>1</td>
         <td>Mohammed</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" /></td>
         <td>2</td>
         <td>Ali</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

and we want to get the first item of each rows, and check whether the checkbox is checked or not.

#### We can do it easly using JS Table APIs.

1. Get the table by it's ID.

```js
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
```

2. Get the table rows

> I use Array.from() to convert HTMLCollection to normal array, so I can use Array APIs (Like .forEach).

```js
var rows = Array.from(table.rows);
```

3. Loop into table rows, and get cells of each row.

```js
rows.map((row) => {
  var cells = Array.from(row.cells);
  
  // TODO add logic here.
});
```

4. Get the `firstChild` of first cell.

```js
rows.map((row) => {
  var cells = Array.from(row.cells);

  if (Array.isArray(cells) && cells.length > 0) {
    var firstChild = cells[0].firstChild;

    console.log(firstChild.checked);
  }
});
```

[Live Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-69903509-7ny3b)